# Is there a way to turn a verb into a noun in French

Tags: verbes, noms

I was thinking recently about French. I noticed how with a lot of verbs in English you can just add -er to the end to turn it into a noun like "someone who `verb`s" like how you can take run and turn it into runner, which is someone who runs.  Is there a way to do this in French?  If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Le suffixe « eur » permet souvent de convertir un verbe en nom. Quelques exemples:

- courir -> coureur
- marcher -> marcheur
- programmer -> programmeur
- vendre -> vendeur